# api provider dashboard shows duplicate calls from curl (curl duplicates requests)

Tags: php, api, curl

The curl request is sent twice:

```
$curl = curl_init();
$url ='http://api.ipstack.com/'.$ip.'?access_key='.$key.'';
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Store the data:
$json = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: There's no reason I see in those few lines why it would be sent twice.  How did you come to the conclusion that it is sent twice?  You'll probably need to show the rest of the code in this file.

Comment: Is this code snippet taken from a function? if so, I think you need to check that function if it is called twice or not

Comment: If you are using Wordpress, put this after your `wp_footer` call. Solved it for me.

Comment: Actually, sorry, I take it back – this worked briefly but it is now reverting to two API uses per call. Perhaps IPStack is doing this on purpose to run down the free tier faster...?